# Rails 4: Simple Custom route redirecting to show action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I'm very new to rails and I'm having trouble with routes. I'm trying to link between views in two different controllers.

In clients#index

```
<li><%= link_to "Manage Client Payments", payments_per_client_path %></li>
```

In Payments Controller:

```
  def payments_per_client
    @payment = Payment.all
  end
```

In routes file:

```
  resources :payments

  resources :direct_debits

  resources :clients do
    resources :payments
  end

   controller :payments do
    get 'payments/payments_per_client' => 'payments#payments_per_client', :as => :payments_per_client
   end
```

The problem is that url for 'Manage Client Payments' displays in my browser as:

```
/payments/payments_per_client
```

but the link redirects to payments#show. I have no idea why this is happening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just change the route path as follows and remove controller block

```
match 'payments/payments_per_client' => 'payments#payments_per_client', :as => :payments_per_client
```

Comment: Yes you can reorder the roots, it is also fine

Comment: if I remove the controller block, where do I then put any variable declarations further down the line? This is an action that's going to have quite a bit going on.

Answer (score 0):

u need to reorder your routes

```
controller :payments do
    get 'payments/payments_per_client' => 'payments#payments_per_client', :as => :payments_per_client
end
resources :payments

resources :direct_debits

resources :clients do
   resources :payments
end
```

becoz your `resouces :payments` already have a routes /payments/:id which is the routes for your payments show page that's why `payments_per_clien`t is treated as an id and it redirects you to show page.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
get 'payments/payments_per_client', to: 'payments#payments_per_client', as: :payments_per_client
```

or

```
match 'payments/payments_per_client' => 'payments#payments_per_client', as: :payments_per_client
```

or

```
match 'payments/payments_per_client' => 'payments#payments_per_client', as: :payments_per_client, via: :get
```